# How to hide More button in swiftui tabview iam using more than 7 tabs

Tags: swiftui-tabview

I added more than 7 view controllers to the tabview, it shows more at the end, I want to disable, or hide it?

Comment: You already asked this question. Don’t repeat yourself please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219250/swiftui-tabview-im-using-more-than-5-tabs-it-showing-more-option-in-views-how

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUi TabView I'm Using More Than 5 Tabs. It Showing More Option In Views How To Hide It?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219250/swiftui-tabview-im-using-more-than-5-tabs-it-showing-more-option-in-views-how)

Comment: None of the above mentioned questions is available anymore, how to hide the "More" button?